# Bash Grep Takes 3 Days To Run. Anyway to Enhance it?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a script like this that I would like to seek some suggestions on enhancing it.

```
cd /home/output/
cat R*op.txt > R.total.op.txt
awk '{if( (length($8)>9) || ($8 ~ /^AAA/) ) {print $0}}' R.total.op.txt > temp && mv temp R.total.op.txt

cat S*op.txt > S.total.op.txt
awk '{if( (length($8)>9) || ($8 ~ /^AAA/) ) {print $0}}' S.total.op.txt > temp && mv temp S.total.op.txt

cat R.total.op.txt S.total.op.txt | awk '{print $4}' | sort -k1,1 | awk '!x[$1]++' > genes.txt
rm *total.op.txt
head genes.txt

cd /home/output/
for j in R1_with-genename R2_with-genename S1_with-genename S2_with-genename
do
**for i in `cat genes.txt`; do cat $j'.op.txt' | grep -w $i >> $j'_'$i'_gene.txt'**;done
done
ls -m1 *gene.txt | wc -l
find . -size 0 -delete
ls -m1 *gene.txt | wc -l
rm genes.txt

cd /home/output/
for i in `ls *gene.txt`
do
paste <(awk '{print $4"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$13}' $i | awk '!x[$1]++' | awk '{print $1}') <(awk '{print $4"\t"$8"\t"$9}' $i | awk '{if( (length($2)>9) || ($2 ~ /^AAA/) ) {print $0}}' | sort -k2,2 | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }') <(awk '{print $4"\t"$8"\t"$9}' $i| awk '{if( (length($2)>9) || ($2 ~ /^AAA/) ) {print $0}}' | sort -k2,2 | wc -l) <(awk '{print $4"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$13}' $i | awk '{if( (length($2)>9) || ($2 ~ /^AAA/) ) {print $0}}' | sort -k2,2 | grep -v ":::" | wc -l) > $i'_stats.txt'
done
rm *gene.txt

cd /home/output/
for j in R1_with-genename R2_with-genename S1_with-genename S2_with-genename
do
cat $j*stats.txt > $j'.final.txt'
done
rm *stats.txt

cd /home/output/
for i in `ls *final.txt`
do
sed "1iGene_Name\tMean1\tCalculated\tbases" $i > temp && mv temp $i
done
head *final.txt
```

The very first for loop (marked with asterisks) that has cat genes.txt is the grep loop that is taking 3 days to finish. Can someone please advice any enhancements to the command and if this entire script can be made into a single command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling `grep` once per word in the file? Ewwww.

Comment: Instead of running `grep` repeatedly for each word, use a single `awk` script that writes the matching lines to the corresponding file.

Comment: This script is better suited for codereview.SE.

Comment: That's not one `grep` taking days, that's **thousands of** `grep`s. Which is to say -- your answer is "don't do that".

Comment: One place you might start, by the way, is [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Another is [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Another is http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: can `grep  -F cat genes.txt $j'.op.txt'  ` help ?

Comment: And I agree that [codereview.se] is probably the better forum for this. Over here on SO, we expect a question to be focused immediately and directly on the problem one is asking about, with other code eliminated, and a [mcve] provided when a question revolves around code.

Comment: (Also see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: @xiawi That won't work because the matches for each word in `genes.txt` needs to go into different output files.

Comment: So there is no better way in other languages other than bash grep? I posted it on Codereview. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: To be clear, what I meant by "don't do that" was "don't run `grep` inside a loop". While `awk` is your best choice here, compared to what you were doing already, even a native-bash `while read` loop using native string comparison logic (no external tools such as `grep`, `awk` or otherwise) on a line-by-line basis would be an improvement.

Comment: (and "bash grep" isn't a thing -- `grep` is not part of `bash`, it's a completely separate tool, and you can use it even without having bash installed at all).

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the nested loops with a single `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR = NR {words[$0] = "\\b" $0 "\\b"; next}
     { for (i in words) if ($0 ~ words[i]) {
        fn = FILENAME "_" i "_gene.txt";
        print >> fn;
        close(fn);
     }' genes.txt {{R,S}{1,2}_with-genename}.op.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a sed script:

```
# name script
SEDSCRIPT=split.sed

# Make sure it is empty
echo "" > ${SEDSCRIPT}

# Loop through all the words in genes.txt and
# create sed command that will write that line to a file
for word in `cat genes.txt`; do
  echo "/${word}/w ${word}.txt" >> ${SEDSCRIPT}
done

basenames="R1_with-genename R2_with-genename S1_with-genename S2_with-genename"

# Loop over input files
for name in "${basenames}"; do
  # Run sed script against file
  sed -n -f ${SEDSCRIPT} ${name}.op.txt

  # Move the temporary files created by sed to their permanent names 
  for word in `cat genes.txt`; do
    mv ${word}.txt ${name}_${word}_gene.txt
  done
done
```